# Convert list pairwise to dictionaries?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list, and I'd like to convert it into a list of dictionaries in Python.

My list is:

```
a = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
```

I'd like to convert it something like this:

```
[
    {'Key': 'a', 'Value': 'b'},
    {'Key': 'c', 'Value': 'd'},
    {'Key': 'e', 'Value': 'f'}
]
```

Comment: You have 2 keys in each dictionary, 1 named `'Key'` and 1 named `'Value'`, this naming is confusing at best. Also when you ask a question like this, it's good to show what you've attempted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) and a list comprehension are the way to go:

```
>>> a = ["a","b","c","d","e","f"]
>>> [{'key': k, 'value': v} for k, v in zip(a[::2], a[1::2])]
[{'value': 'b', 'key': 'a'}, {'value': 'd', 'key': 'c'}, {'value': 'f', 'key': 'e'}]
```

Notice how the list is sliced with a step of two starting at 0 and 1 and then *zipped*.

Answer (score 3):

Better way will be to use `itertool.izip_longest()` with *list comprehension* as it will place value as `None` in case elements are odd in number. For example:

```
>>> from itertools import izip_longest
>>> odd_list = ["a", "b", "c"]
>>> [{'key': k, 'value': v} for k, v in izip_longest(odd_list[::2], odd_list[1::2])]
[{'value': 'b', 'key': 'a'}, {'value': None, 'key': 'c'}]
#                                       ^ Value as None
```

However if it is safe to assume *even count* of elements, you may use `zip()` as well as:

```
>>> my_list = ["a","b","c","d","e","f"]
>>> [{'key': k, 'value': v} for k, v in zip(my_list[::2], my_list[1::2])]
[{'value': 'b', 'key': 'a'}, {'value': 'd', 'key': 'c'}, {'value': 'f', 'key': 'e'}]
```

Comment: This doesn't produce the result OP is asking for.

Comment: @ZeroPiraeus: That is because dicts are unordered. Values are mapped with same key as is desired. Even using OrderedDict won't display the result in the way he wants

Comment: No, it's because your code was wrong before aisbaa fixed it.

Comment: Oh Yes. Updated it. I missed the part that they are need to be jumped by 2

Answer (score 1):

This can be one way of doing it:

```
lst = [{"Key": a[2 * i], "Value": a[2 * i + 1]} for i in range(len(a) / 2)]
```

*Note*: list `a` must have even number or elements in order to work